# Word game in Python and if statements problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a word game in python. It's from a crashing course that teaches the basics of python.
I'm stuck in this part where I wanna make the program "break" after the character's or the "monster's" (the opponent) health go below 0. The course teaches you to create a boolean variable that makes the game end when the health is <=0, but it's not working. I think is something with my "if" statements, but i'm truly lost. Sorry for the English or some rule broken, it's my first post in Stack.

```
import time
import random

player = {'name':input('Escolha um nome para o seu personagem '), 'attack': 10, 'heal': 16, 'health':100}
monster = {'name': input('Escolha seu oponente '), 'attack':12,'health':100}

game_running = True


while game_running == True :

    player_won = False
    monster_won = False

    print(f'Selecione a ação do {player["name"]}')
    print('1)Attack')
    print('2) Heal')
    player_action = input()

    if player_action == '1':
        print(f'{player["name"]} atacou {monster["name"]}')
        monster['health'] = monster['health'] - random.randint(0,11)
        print({monster["health"]})
        if monster['health'] <= 0:
            player_won == True
        else:
            print(f'Agora é o turno de {monster["name"]}')
            # time.sleep(0)
            player['health'] = player['health'] - random.randint(0,13)
            print(f"A saúde do jogador é de: {player['health']}")


        if player['health'] <= 0:
                monster_won == True

    elif player_action == '2':
        print(f'{player["name"]} se recuperou')
        player['health'] = player['health'] + player['heal']
        time.sleep(0)
        print(f"O player se recuperou e agora sua saúde é de : {player['health']}")
    else:
        print('invalid command')

    if player_won == True or monster_won == True:
            game_running == False
```

Comment: Tty put a `break` inside the `if player_won == .....` to break out of while loop.

Comment: Example of `break` statement: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

Comment: your code is correct, you just need to assign the value to boolean. use `=` instead of `==` where u assign player_won and monster_won

Comment: The issue  is that `if player_won or monster_won: game_running == False`. when it needs to be `game_running = false`. You are checking instead of setting the value of `game_running`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, you just need to assign the value to boolean. use `=` instead of `==` where u assign player_won and monster_won and game_running

```py
if monster['health'] <= 0:
    player_won = True # = instead of ==
if player['health'] <= 0:
    monster_won = True # again, same

if player_won == True or monster_won == True:
    game_running = False # here too
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `==` comparison operator rather than `=`. One must use `==` in if statements to compare values, but it will not assign a value to anything.

So, you need to change these lines of code

```
if monster['health'] <= 0:
            player_won == True
```

```
if player['health'] <= 0:
                monster_won == True
```

```
if player_won == True or monster_won == True:
            game_running == False
```

to this:

```
if monster['health'] <= 0:
            player_won = True
```

```
if player['health'] <= 0:
                monster_won = True
```

```
if player_won == True or monster_won == True:
            game_running = False
```